# Ionic Run Android error - on Ubuntu 16

Tags: android, node.js, cordova, ubuntu, ionic-framework

I'm running Ubuntu 16.

Here's my System information:

```
Your system information:

Cordova CLI: 6.3.1
Gulp version:  CLI version 1.2.2
Gulp local:   Local version 3.9.1
Ionic Framework Version: 1.2.4-nightly-1917
Ionic CLI Version: 2.0.0
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.0.0-beta.20
OS: Distributor ID: Ubuntu Description: Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS 
Node Version: v4.4.7
```

When I try to do a **sudo ionic run android** or a **sudo ionic build android** from my project directory, I get this output:

```
Running command: /home/simon/flash-trader/hooks/after_prepare/010_add_platform_class.js /home/simon/flash-trader


add to body class: platform-android


Caught exception:
 TypeError: Can't call method on  undefined
    at TypeError (native)
    at module.exports (/home/simon/flash-trader/node_modules/karma/node_modules/core-js/modules/_defined.js:3:28)
    at createHTML (/home/simon/flash-trader/node_modules/karma/node_modules/core-js/modules/_string-html.js:7:19)
    at bold (/home/simon/flash-trader/node_modules/karma/node_modules/core-js/modules/es6.string.bold.js:5:12)
    at cb (/usr/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/ionic-app-lib/node_modules/winston/lib/winston/logger.js:206:7)
    at done (/usr/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/ionic-app-lib/node_modules/winston/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:167:19)
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/ionic-app-lib/node_modules/winston/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:40:16
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/ionic-app-lib/node_modules/winston/lib/winston/logger.js:193:9
    at Console.log (/usr/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/ionic-app-lib/node_modules/winston/lib/winston/transports/console.js:127:3)
    at emit (/usr/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/ionic-app-lib/node_modules/winston/lib/winston/logger.js:186:17)
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/ionic-app-lib/node_modules/winston/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:157:13
    at _each (/usr/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/ionic-app-lib/node_modules/winston/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:57:9)
    at Object.async.each (/usr/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/ionic-app-lib/node_modules/winston/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:156:9)
    at Logger.log (/usr/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/ionic-app-lib/node_modules/winston/lib/winston/logger.js:214:9)
    at target.(anonymous function) [as error] (/usr/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/ionic-app-lib/node_modules/winston/lib/winston/common.js:54:18)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/ionic/lib/utils/cordova.js:83:11)

Mind letting us know? https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-cli/issues


Caught exception:
 TypeError: Can't call method on  undefined
    at TypeError (native)
    at module.exports (/home/simon/flash-trader/node_modules/karma/node_modules/core-js/modules/_defined.js:3:28)
    at createHTML (/home/simon/flash-trader/node_modules/karma/node_modules/core-js/modules/_string-html.js:7:19)
    at bold (/home/simon/flash-trader/node_modules/karma/node_modules/core-js/modules/es6.string.bold.js:5:12)
    at cb (/usr/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/ionic-app-lib/node_modules/winston/lib/winston/logger.js:206:7)
    at done (/usr/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/ionic-app-lib/node_modules/winston/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:167:19)
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/ionic-app-lib/node_modules/winston/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:40:16
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/ionic-app-lib/node_modules/winston/lib/winston/logger.js:193:9
    at Console.log (/usr/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/ionic-app-lib/node_modules/winston/lib/winston/transports/console.js:127:3)
    at emit (/usr/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/ionic-app-lib/node_modules/winston/lib/winston/logger.js:186:17)
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/ionic-app-lib/node_modules/winston/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:157:13
    at _each (/usr/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/ionic-app-lib/node_modules/winston/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:57:9)
    at Object.async.each (/usr/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/ionic-app-lib/node_modules/winston/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:156:9)
    at Logger.log (/usr/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/ionic-app-lib/node_modules/winston/lib/winston/logger.js:214:9)
    at target.(anonymous function) [as error] (/usr/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/ionic-app-lib/node_modules/winston/lib/winston/common.js:54:18)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/ionic/lib/utils/cordova.js:83:11)
```

Yes, the exact same error twice. I've set up my phone on Ubuntu as specified on developer.android.com. Debug mode is enabled. All my environment variables are set (I believe.) I installed the Android SDK through Android Studio.

This error is pretty clandestine. Has anyone seen it before?

However, ionic serve builds and runs the project perfectly.

A Google search turns up a few related questions but nothing that seems to match my exact situation. Thanks for the help.

Comment: You should try to remove `node_modules` and do another `npm install`

Comment: I deleted `/node_modules` and also `/platforms` directly from the filesystem, the folders in my project folder, that is. I then did, in the following order: `sudo npm install -g cordova`, `sudo npm install -g ionic`, `sudo npm install`.

I then tried another `ionic build android`, and after Ionic re-added android for me because I forgot to do so, I got the same error.

Comment: Have you seen this github opened issue : https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-cli/issues/984 ? It is still opened but the last post give a hack to make it work. Also, I find it weird that you need to use sudo to run all your command. It is normal use of linux. You should fix this issue too (search for ways to use npm without sudo).

Comment: good idea. im looking in to both those things. Didnt know sudo was weird thanks

Answer (score 0):

In the end, what i did was a confluence of things.

I had to do a `chown -R $USER ~/[project name]` so that we don't have to `**sudo** ionic`. Sudo uses different environment variables to the rest of the shell apparently, and so ANDROID_HOME, etc., wasn't accessible.

I also had to change my JAVA_HOME because it was set like [jdk-path]/bin, and should just be [jdk-path]/

It might also have made a difference that I uninstalled the version of the app that I had downloaded from the Google Play Store (as the app I'm trying to build is already published).

I also changed a line in `cordova.js` that said something like `log("foo").green.bold` to just `log(foo).green` in the liveReload function.

Good luck if you get the same problem.